# Монолексема

Tags: лексика

Дайте,пожалуйста,полное определение термину "монолексема"

Answer (score 1):

Можно предложить следующий вариант для определения "монолексемы":

Монолексема -  это отдельное слово, выступающее в качестве номинативной единицы.

Монолексемам  противопоставлены полилексемы (словесные комплексы)  – словосочетания различного вида, также имеющие номинативную функцию. К ним относятся как фразеологические единицы, так и словосочетания терминологического или образно-художественного характера.

Указанные термины характерны для различных работ, связанных с анализом словарного состава текста, например: «Мы установили, что в текстах былин функционируют два типа номинативных единиц – словесный комплекс (17%) и монолексема (83%)». Также эти понятия важны при переводе литературы с одного языка на другой. К примеру, обсуждаемыми являются вопросы о переводе фразеологических сочетаний монолексемой или иным способом.